# Find the equilibrium of the given ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the following non homogeneous, autonomous ODE:
$$y'(t) = Ay(t)+b $$ with $y(0) = y_0$ where $y_0 \in R^{2m}$ is a known vector.
Also , $A$ is $2m$ by $2m$ and invertible, and b $\in R^{2m}$.

What is the equilibrium point of the above ODE?

Comment: Do you know the definition of an eq. point of an ODE?

Comment: Is it identical to the fixed point of a function? I'm not sure ...

Comment: 1) It is "equilibrium solution (or point)", not "equilibrium". 2) A equilibrium solution is a solution that no longer changes with $t$. If $y(t)$ is an equilibrium solution, what is $y'(t)$?

Comment: Okay so finding the equilibrium point to this ODE is similar to solving $Ay(t)+b=0$?

Comment: @JK Math yeah you could say so. You can think of it as the point such that if $y_0$ is the eq. point, then $y(t) = y_0$ for all $t>0$.

Comment: And how do we prove that? And if not how would we find another equilibrium point, expressed in terms of matrices A and b? Would that be $A^{-1}b$?

Comment: If $A$, $b$ are constant and $A$ invertible, the equilibrium point is unique and given by $A^{-1}b$.

Comment: @achillehui $-A^{-1}b$

Comment: @L'universo oops, you're right! I should go to sleep ;-p